# Java Switch Statement Number Varies

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

I was wondering if its possible to check for a range of numbers when doing a switch statement (switching an int). Like case: 1 - 50: // code.

Would this be possible instead of writing every case? Thanks.

Comment: Could you rephrase what exactly you want since there is a misunderstanding. lol

Comment: Maybe you could switch to groovy, as it allows [ranges in the switch statement](http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2009/08/groovy-goodness-switch-statement.html) :-)

Comment: @Developer42 Please accept an answer, as I'd like to know if I should remove my answer or not since your question is confusing.

Answer (score 4):

If the question aims at ranges (like [groovy supports](http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2009/08/groovy-goodness-switch-statement.html)), without having to list every item, the answer is: unfortunately not. Such a broad range would be implemented using an if, instead of a switch. Details to usage of `switch` can be found in the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: This is WRONG. It IS possible, just not logical. Why is the highest rated solution incorrect?

Comment: @martin "I was wondering if its possible to check for a range of numbers when doing a switch statement"

Comment: I dont conceive an "enumeration" (listing every single value) as a range (giving start and end value), like the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, simply ommit the `break` of the ancestor `case`

```
int test = 1;

switch(test)
{
     case 0:
     case 1:
     case 2:
         System.out.println("test");
     break;
}
```

This won't print `test` unless `test` is equal to `0, 1 or 2`.

However, I don't see any point in doing this when you can do

```
if(integer >= 10 && integer <= 50)
```

**Edit :** I think I misunderstood this question, if the question was actually to know if it is possible to specify a range using only one `case` keyword like

```
case 1-50:
break;
```

Then no, it is not possible, but once again, you can simply use the `if`. Now you have answer to both possibilities of your question.

Comment: I suppose, this would be impractical the given example (1-50).

Comment: @martin the question is about if it is possible or not.

Comment: "possible instead of writing every case". BTW, the link explains this technique of omittint the break.

Comment: @martin After re-reading the second part of the question, I think you were right. I edited my answer to give answer to both possibilities. You should edit your post so I can remove the `downvote` i first gave you :)

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is no. You have specific cases within a switch statement that allows the code execution to have logic. Unless you specify all cases that need to be handled, the code execution will proceed to the default case which is not what you want.

The question I would as you is **why** would you want to? It is most definitely possible. You can you a switch statement where you have a case for every integer 1-50, and if the integer falls under this range, the corresponding case will execute.

With that being said, this is **not** the way this should be handled. The proper way to handle a situation like this is with an if statement: `if (x >= 1 && x <= 50)`...

Comment: OP know that he/she can have a case for every integer 1-50. but _"Would this be possible instead of writing every case?"_

Answer (score 0):

As @martin's answer, you cannot do it in the switch. But I think you can abstract a new case list according to this kind of requirement. e.g:

```
CASE_1: x>1 && x<50
CASE_2: x>50 && x < 100
...
```

You can define a function to convert the case before you use the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can achieve that with a trick, see bellow:

```
int my_number = 30;
int switcher = my_number;

if (my_number >= 1 && my_number <= 50)
    switcher = 1;

switch (switcher) 
{ 
    case 1:  
        // My number is in range 1 - 50 
        return true;
    case 51: 
        // My number is not in range of 1 - 50.
        return false;
}
```